# DOMPDF: Laravel failed to load CSS when downloading PDf

Tags: php, css, laravel, dompdf

### ViewBlade

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="all">

 .HVMC{font-family: "Herr Von Muellerhoff", cursive !important}
 .MDHC{font-family: "Mr De Haviland", cursive !important;}
 .ABC{font-family: "Alex Brush", cursive !important;}
 .CCC{font-family: "Cedarville Cursive", cursive !important;}
 .LBAC{font-family: "La Belle Aurore", cursive !important;}

.img-list {
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 1310px;
}

html,body
{
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   background-color:lightgray;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id="maindiv">
  @foreach ($proposalfromTemplate as $proposal)
        {!! $proposal->html !!}
  @endforeach  
<div>
</html>
```

### Controller

```
PDF::setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled' => TRUE, 'enable_javascript' => TRUE]);

$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');

return $pdf->download($pid . '.pdf');
```

When I return View It works fine, but when I return $pdf->download() it not including CSS, in Blade file 
the given data is a text file which I get from storage so I am not able to add CSS on it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to render your HTML first before load into DOMPDF

```
public function generateXYZ()
{
    PDF::setOptions(['isRemoteEnabled' => TRUE, 'enable_javascript' => TRUE]);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $html = view('your.view.path')->render();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    return $pdf->download('card.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Darshit Hedpara it shows an error because $pdf is not defined

Comment: bro, It's just I typo mistake in my code. I have not run above code it just for your reference. you can replace $pdf with $dompdf.